# Drop caps and Centered text

Tags: html, css

I have some centered text and I need a dropcap implemented for that text. All of the examples i found use float:left css property for the dropcap effect which aligns the first letter to the left while all of the text is left centered.

Any way around the issue?

Comment: Could you please explain what you're after a bit better, it's somewhat hard to understand at the moment? An image perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

What about this.
crossbrowser with extra markup

**HTML**

```
<p>
<span class="dropcap">L</span> orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tristique lobortis orci ac lacinia.
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropcap {font-family:arial; float: left; color:green; font-size: 125px; line-height: 60px; padding-top: 4px; padding-right: 8px; padding-left: 3px; }
```

Demo: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/A8ZAH/)

Comment: it does not tacle the issue i have at all, see my fidle link what i am talking about http://jsfiddle.net/A8ZAH/1/

Comment: if you are using drop cap style for the paragraph than according to standard of paragraph it should not be center